# Jquery Mobile automatically adds &nbsp

Tags: jquery-mobile

i've got this code using Jquery Mobile :

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" checked="">
      <label for="checkbox-1a">Cheetos</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a">
      <label for="checkbox-2a">Doritos</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3a" id="checkbox-3a">
      <label for="checkbox-3a">Fritos</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-4a" id="checkbox-4a">
      <label for="checkbox-4a">Sun Chips</label>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
 </div>
```

The problem is that when i load the page the codes looks like this :

```
<div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="ui-checkbox">
```

I've skipped the whole code, the problem is in the

```
&nbsp;
```

that should not be there.
Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: jQM doesn't add `&nbsp;`, your editor does. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ywLquv88/

Comment: Nope, source code is the same as posted, both on editor and on web server. It changes once the browser loads it, tested on Chrome, Explorer and Firefox

Comment: copy code in the posted fiddle above and try again. jQM doesn't add `&nbsp;`. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/widgets/controlgroup.js

Comment: check there http://jsfiddle.net/ywLquv88/2/

Comment: because it is copied/pasted from your editor. If you remove/disable jQM, the spaces will remain intact http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ywLquv88/3/

Comment: This has come up at least one more time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037017/jquery-mobile-1-4-header-spacing/30037276 and the accepted answer is actually very useful, so I disagree with pretty much all of the close reasons. Vote to reopen.

Comment: So reopen and close as a duplicate? Sounds like should just flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @PatrickM no, the question I linked to is newer, and also it's not a direct duplicate, but the underlying cause is the same. I mentioned it to refute the "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" assertion. The new question, and the other 5 upvotes on the accepted answer for this one belie that. It's difficult to reproduce the issue directly on Stack Overflow because the whitespace characters aren't obvious in the text, but that's not the OP's fault. Clearly the issue does arise (can still be reproduced, not a simple typo), and the question definitely has value.

Comment: (if it helps, I answered the other question by using web inspector, noticing unexplained `&nbsp;`s in the DOM, then searching for `jquery mobile header nbsp`, which led me to this question, which helped me to solve the problem. This question/answer were therefore invaluable)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This problem comes when copying and pasting the source code from their website.

In fact in this way you copy also invisible blank spaces which are converted as `&nbsp;` by the browser and make the last block go down.

To solve the issue simply remove all the spaces between the tags and all will be displayed correctly.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this answer. I found the &nbsp; escape codes inserted into my popup and could not figure out why. I copy-pasted from jquery mobile documentation site... my editor is Eclipse for more information on this.

Comment: I have the same problem, but im downloading the source code in the header, so the problem doesn't occur because i dont't copy any code. I also inserted a custom jqm theme in my project ... Could there be a problem in the custom theme files ? Im using the phonegap emulator and the problem also occurs on my phone, so the editor is also not the reason.

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways you can remove the automatic default padding.

First

```
<div style="padding: 0;">...</div>
```

Second: Define an id for the div tag and set padding to 0 in css

```
<div id="myID">
#myID{ padding:0; }
```