# Spaces between jquery mobile controlgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to utilize a jQuery Mobile collapsible widget. However, using the code straight from [their site](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible/) (specifically the Legend), I noticed there are spaces between the control group.

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1-a" id="checkbox-1-a" />
            <label for="checkbox-1-a">One</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2-a" id="checkbox-2-a" />
            <label for="checkbox-2-a">Two</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3-a" id="checkbox-3-a" />
            <label for="checkbox-3-a">Three</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Is there a way to remove these? I tried going through the default css to see if there is an attribute I can change but I couldn't find anything. Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c90v41ab/2/) that shows the spaces and my code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Mobile automatically adds &nbsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784062/jquery-mobile-automatically-adds-nbsp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gaps are a result of the whitespaces and line breaks in the html markup. This does it for me:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1-a" id="checkbox-1-a"><label for="checkbox-1-a">One</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2-a" id="checkbox-2-a"><label for="checkbox-2-a">Two</label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3-a" id="checkbox-3-a"><label for="checkbox-3-a">Three</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c90v41ab/3/)

Or, making the html markup a little less ugly:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
        <legend>Legend</legend>
        <div data-role="controlgroup">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1-a" id="checkbox-1-a"><label
                for="checkbox-1-a">One</label><input
                type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2-a" id="checkbox-2-a"><label
                for="checkbox-2-a">Two</label><input
                type="checkbox" name="checkbox-3-a" id="checkbox-3-a"><label
                for="checkbox-3-a">Three</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It appears I did have extra spaces and breaks I didn't need. Thank you!