# JQuery Mobile 1.4 header spacing

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

When I place a search text input element inside a div in my header it gets a lot of space added to the top. I've tried setting margin/padding 0 on all the elements but the extra space is still there:

```
<div><input data-theme="a" data-type="text" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/155pr11x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by some extra non-breaking space characters in your source which get translated to `&nbsp;`.

I'm guessing you've been caught by copying/pasting code from their website, see [Jquery Mobile automatically adds &nbsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784062/jquery-mobile-automatically-adds-nbsp)

Updated fiddle without the whitespace http://jsfiddle.net/155pr11x/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to view the HTML elements of interest using "More Tools / Developer tools" with a Chrome browser or the "Firebug" add-on with a Firefox browser. Either tool should show you why you are getting the spacing that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Input element was not closed here's the  [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/masterOpti/155pr11x/2/)

```
<input data-theme="a" data-type="text" data-mini="true" data-clear-btn="true"/>
```

Comment: I think you've found a bug in jsfiddle rather than solving the problem. If you go to the original fiddle and add the `/`, and straight away delete it without running, and then click 'run', the spacing will be fixed, even though you didn't actually change anything. I suspect jsfiddle is translating the weird space characters to normal whitespace when you make the edit, so this doesn't fix the actual problem.

Comment: In HTML5 `<input>` and `<input/>` are equivalent - you don't have to close `<input>`s (and in fact strictly speaking you shouldn't)

Comment: seems like the problem is with the copy & paste i think while pasting the source code into fiddle white-spaces are also get pasted. code with removed whitespace --> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/masterOpti/155pr11x/4/)